# How to partition exactly 50GB of usable space

Tags: windows, partitioning

I use the mega service for cloud storage, which gives 50GB of free space (please correct me if it is not exactly 50GB)

I also use a great backup software for imaging my system drive. I really like this because it lets me recover easily from disaster.

Currently I store the mega sync on my D drive which is mechanical.

My boot drive C has "plenty" of free space and is an SSD. I would like to create a partition on it so that it can house the mega sync. However that's all it would do so I don't want to waste any space more than necessary.

This way I can free up space on my mechanical drive, which i need to do. Use up some space I'm not using on the SSD (i try to keep my boot drive small so i can back it up easily) w/o it affecting the backup and still be able to do a system drive imaging backup.

So my question is how can I calculate exactly the partition size I need to specify when creating the partition. Probably I will use minitool partition wizard free if it allows partitioning the boot disk since I already have that installed.

I'm not sure even if when you specify a parition size when creating a new partition is that supposed to be GB or GiB ? I assume that GiB is what the drive manfuacturers say and mega 50GB allowance would be GB.. or did I get that backwards?

Comment: I think you got got it right re: GB and GiB but I don't see the point in having a separated partition for that, a folder is enough. And, in any case, you'll never use *exactly* 50GB of your quota. At most something around but less than that.

Comment: there's no way to exclude folders in my backup program when imaging the system partition (or any partition)... otherwise I love the backup program (AOEMEI) it is simple to use and free. Also yes I do never use exactly the entire quote, but I get close occasionally and have to clean out some old files

Comment: So, just create a partition slightly larger than the quota. Since it's not a system partition it doesn't need that much free space.

Comment: ok, i forgot i can just resize partitions easily with these tools. So if there are any problems they are easily remedied.

Comment: Since "size" and "size on disk" [differ in general](https://superuser.com/q/66825/432690) and since any filesystem needs some space for metadata, and because of tricks [like this](https://superuser.com/q/1030800/432690), trying to *exactly* match "usable space" of another filesystem is futile, maybe unless you can match every aspect of the two filesystems (and I doubt you can do this between this cloud storage and, say, local NTFS). So "a partition slightly larger than the quota" is a reasonable approach.

Comment: yes this is what I was thinking - but I was thinking there would be some way to calculate this but i guess not

Comment: One option, to avoid the pain of repatitioning your disk, is to create and mount a 50GB VHD file... less messing around and a lot quicker and easier to get to the size you want as it's just deleting and recreating a file on disk: https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/gg318052(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: windows 10 pro (not creators)