# Why ls -l total is 0 even even there are files in the directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ls, ubuntu-20.04

I have a directory, inside that, I have created 2 files and have written some content in these files when I run `ls -l`. It still displays the total as `0`. Why? It should return some positive integer.

I already referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401704/what-is-that-total-in-the-very-first-line-after-ls-l/33730697#33730697) answer, and I am convinced with the explanation. But why total 0, I still didn't understand.

I am running this command in ubuntu (20.04 LTS) using Windows Subsystem for Linux on Windows 10.

[image: ls output]

Comment: Actually seeing the output you're getting would be great. You can [edit] the question.

Comment: @gronostaj done, please check

Comment: Similar question in context of pure Windows (no WSL, no `ls`): [*How can a file's size on disk be 0 bytes when there's data in it?*](https://superuser.com/q/1030800/432690)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that's because you're using WSL on a NTFS volume. NTFS will store small files directly in file's record inside MFT (Master File Table). For larger files this space in a file record would be reserved, but not used. So a small file is essentially taking no extra space on disk, except for what the file record would take anyway, therefore producing a total of 0.

Comment: so in native ubuntu, it will not show total 0?

Comment: @viveknuna It doesn't. https://i.stack.imgur.com/201Vl.png

Comment: It shows up for me under the circumstances that OP described, but I'm using native Debian 11 and BTRFS.

Answer (score 0):

[What is "total" in the output of "ls" command? [duplicate]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57132/578951)

total shows disk usage, not item count inside the directory!

> The "total" is the disk usage of listed files (because of -a including
> the  . and .. entries) in blocks (1024 bytes or if POSIXLY_CORRECT is
> set in 512 bytes), not including the content of subdirectories.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question any more than your other answer, the user talks about size. What are you tring to do here? I'm not quite following your answering attempt.

Comment: When you do touch 1, 2, 3, 4 you create a zero length files. Therefore total size is 0

Comment: OP says he added content to files, and you can see they are 11 bytes and 2 bytes.