# Why my file showing 0 bytes if it has data in it?

Tags: windows-10, memory

When I try to delete the file, it's showing 0 bytes:

[image]

Why my file showing 0 bytes if it has data in it?

Comment: It may be wise to run scandisk https://www.computerhope.com/issues/pictures/ch001118-win10-scan-disk-01.jpg & https://www.computerhope.com/issues/pictures/ch001118-win10-scan-disk-02.jpg & https://www.computerhope.com/issues/pictures/ch001118-win10-scan-disk-03.jpg

Comment: We would need more information.  The most likely scenario is file corruption.  Are you able to actually extract the files from the compressed archive?  Instead of submitting a comment you should [edit] your question. In the future, it would be appreciated, if you didn't "demand" somebody fixes the images in your questions.  Links to images are just fine until somebody performs the required [edit] to your question.

Comment: @Ramhound File present in flash drive.

Comment: @AhmedJ - That does not answer my question with regards to if you can extract the compressed file.

Comment: This situation can happen if the file has been opened (locked) exclusively by a process. Because the access is exclusive Windows Explorer can not query any information and thus shows file size as 0 bytes. Also deleting of such files usually fails (unless deleting is explicitly allowed while locked.

Comment: @Robert I can delete that file.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1030800/how-can-a-files-size-on-disk-be-0-bytes-when-theres-data-in-it